# Finding number of lines in a text file, and struct-ing a datapoint with this dimension

Tags: c++, variables, constants

Here is the code straight from my program.

```
 // count how many lines the read text document has, so the datastructure can have the correct dimension.
        int number_of_lines = 0;
        std::string line;
        while (getline(myfile, line)) {
            ++number_of_lines;
        }
        std::cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines;
        // the first line won't have a new line before it, so add one to number_of_lines
        rows = number_of_lines + 1;
        return 0;
    }

    // create a data point structure with "rows" number of rows
    datapoint mypoints[rows];
```

There's a red squiggly line under [rows], saying:

> double rows Error: expression must have a constant value.

Shouldn't the value be constant, as the while loop which added to `number_of_lines` finished before rows used number_of_lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a variable-length array (VLA) in C++.

```
datapoint mypoints[rows];
//                 ^^^^
//                 this is a variable (i.e. not a compile-time constant)
```

What you can do instead is either make a dynamic array:

```
datapoint* mypoints = new datapoint[rows];
// ...
delete [] mypoints;
```

Or use a `vector`:

```
std::vector<datapoint> mypoints(rows); // will default-construct all of them
```

Comment: Using your first suggestion (which should allow me to not have to change the majority of my code), I get a red squiggly line under rows, in: 
new datapoint[rows];

double rows;
Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Set rows to be 
int rows

as the rows will be an integer. Sorted, thank you!

Comment: @Idios Yes, definitely has to be integral. What would an array of 1.5 datapoints mean?